# How does the dot product $F(x) \cdot n(x)$ give the vector components on the surface

Tags: integration, vector-analysis, surface-integrals

Let $F$ be some vector field (say in $\mathbb R^{3})$ and $n$ be the unit vector of the surface. How exactly does $F(x) \cdot n(x)$ (where $\cdot$ is the dot product) give the vector component ("normal component") on the surface needed to calculate the flux in an area $dS$? Is the normal component (let's call it $h(x)$) basically the horizontal component of $F(x)$so that $n(x)$ and $h(x)$ added together will give us $F(x)$. I am confused!

Comment: Flux is about flow *across* the surface, i.e., in the direction of the normal. If the vector field is tangential to the surface, there is $0$ flux. The normal component is the component of $\vec F$ in the direction of the normal vector $\vec n$. What you've written about horizontal is totally confusing.

Comment: How do I get the flow (magnitude and direction) from the unit normal vector field and the vector field?

Comment: The net flow across the surface is gotten by doing the surface integral $\iint_S \vec F\cdot\vec n\,dS$.

Comment: @MinaThuma The **flow** (how individual particles are moving near $x$) has magnitude and direction given by $F(x)$; the **flux** (how much stuff is being transfered through a piece of the surface per unit time) is a scalar (varying from point to point on the surface) given by the normal component $F(x)\cdot n(x)$.